# Unassigned image

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimage

I am having a problem loading some images, and I think `assets.xcassets` is the problem. Some of these images show up like this:

[image]

It says that this image is unassigned, but I have assigned it to be a tab icon. Now, the image isn't even shown in the tab icon. How can I get it to show again?

Comment: Select the image set and make a screenshot of the Attributes inspector please

Comment: @matt I have just fixed it now. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I figured the assets catalog was just hosed in some way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-added the images and that seemed to do the trick. It was quite odd that some were unassigned whilst others weren't.